# How "high up" the dom can I go for DOMMutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to modify all span elements (identified by class='behavior-header-options') by adding a button to each span. The problem is that the spans are loaded dynamically via AJAX calls and so I have to use DOMMutationObserver to listen (observe?) for them to load.

My question is how "high" up the dom can I go to find all spans with the class mentioned above? Basically I'm unsure how to get all the way down to the span I'm looking for. Should I recursively traverse (child.child.child...) until I reach the span i'm looking for?

Im sure i'll get down-voted for this question but i'm really new to JS and especially new to DOMMutationObserver.

Comment: For starters, do you control the ajax that inserts these spans? If so would be easy to manipulate them within success callbacks of ajax

Comment: I do not control that ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing here was, outside of any listener is start with the root of the dom, reload the page and check if the children of that node were defined (that is, when i fired aler(node.child.className + ' ' node.child.id); some value showed up). I kept doing this until the node's child was undefined and then listened on that node. This gave me the right "depth" into the document to listen for.

If there's an easier way to figure out which element to listen on, i'm happy to hear it.